# GPU utilization when running a Console Application

Tags: printf, gpu, cout

I encounter a weird thing when I executed console application in windows 8.1.
My system configuration is:
OS: Windows 8.1
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo
Graphics: ATI Mobility Radeon 4500
The problem occur when I use printf or std::cout in for loop to print about one million information to console.
I used MSI AfterBurner application to monitor GPU performance.
When I run the application GPU utilization changes when I minimize or change the size of the console application window. When I make it small the GPU utilization decreases and when I make it bigger GPU utilization increases. when I minimize it GPU utilization become zero.
I thought maybe windows uses GPU to render the output. Am I right?
Another problem is, GPU utilization is different when using std::cout and printf() in that for loop.

What is really happening there in the CPU and GPU?

Comment: From the title, I thought you are talking about using `printf` **in** the kernel, but this is not the case. You could consider adding your code to the question, but ... this may not even be relevant: You could try to run a `main` (without any OpenCL code!) that only executes the loop (and prints random data from `A`,  `B` and `C`), and see whether you observe the same effect. I think this will be the case, and the reason is most likely what you said: The GPU is busy with updating the console. Someone might give a more profound answer if the question was reworded/retagged accordingly.

Comment: "The problem occur when I use printf or std::cout in for loop to print about one million information to console." - seems a very *artifical* problem to me. *nobody* does that in practice.

Comment: Yes, But I want to know why it is happening? I'm learning OpenCl and I want to measure GPU utilization after execution of OpenCL code GPU continues to work.